# Python - mystery infinite loop

Tags: python, indexing, while-loop, infinite-loop

[I'm taking this Python course online](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/13-lists/#pybox12) and am trying to figure out why this loop is infinite when the x value is 3

```
def mystery(x):
  a = [0, 4, 0, 3, 2]
  while x > 0:
    x = a[x]
  return "Done"
```

mystery(3) runs infinitely.

Is it because it keeps trying to set x to 3 when the list value is already 3?

Comment: Probably instead of `while x > 0: ` you want `while x != a[x]:`. That will handle _both_ of the values that map to themselves, instead of just one of them. But that still wouldn't help if there were any loops  (e.g., `a = [1, 0, 2, 3, 4]` would loop forever on either `0` or `1`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember array indices start from 0, so if

```
a = [0, 4, 0, 3, 2]
```

then `a[3] == 3`

so this line

```
x = a[x]
```

never sets `x` to anything other than 3!

Answer (score 2):

"Is it because it keeps trying to set x to 3 when the list value is already 3?"

Yes. `a[3]` points to `3` in that list. So `x` is just being assigned to `3` repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, x is always 3. initially x is 3 and at index 3 the value of list,i.e a[x] is also 3.Hence infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that list indices start at zero, so a[3]=3.  Then, try unrolling the loop manually:

1. x = 3

   is x=3 > 0, YES
2. x = a[x] = a[3] = 3

   is x=3 > 0, YES
3. x = a[x] = a[3] = 3

   is x=3 > 0, YES

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
def mystery(x):               # Here x = 3
  a = [0, 4, 0, 3, 2]         
  while x > 0:                # Since x = 3 the program enters the loop
    x = a[x]                  # a[3] = 3 and hence x is assigned 3. Again x = 3 and therefore 
                              # the program will get into an infinite loop in the while 
                              # statement.
  return "Done"
```